# Can't pass parameter from template to Django view

Tags: python, html, django

Im passing three parameter from my html template to django view.py. But whenever i click on submit it show me `Page not found` ,. I'm still new in programming and Django. Does anyone know how can I fix this issue?
The expected result is the webpage able to display all the input from the user. The result should display on the same page and not on the other pages.

my template

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Alert Policies</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <p style="font-size:14px">Please select an event parameter as well as the condition type and value that apply.</p>

        <!-- parameter drop down -->
        <form action="send" method="post">
            <label for="Parameter"> <b style="font-size:13px" >  Event parameter to evaluate </b></label>
            <select name="Parameter" id="Parameter" style="width:340px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
                <option disabled selected value>select a parameter</option>
                <option value="Subject">Subject</option>
                <option value="Text">Text</option>

            </select>
            <br><br>

            <label for="Condition">   <b style="font-size:13px" >  Type of condition </b></label>
            <select name="Condition" id="Condition" style="width:340px; margin-left:69px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
                <option disabled selected value>select a condition</option>
                <option value="Equals">Equals</option>
                <option value="Contain">Contain</option>
                <option value="NotContain">Does not contain</option>

            </select>
            <br><br>

            <label for="valuetomatch"> <b style="font-size:13px" > Value to match</b></label>
            <input type="text" id="valuetomatch" name="valuetomatch" style="width:333px; margin-left:80px; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;">
            <br>
            <br>
<button class="button"><span>OK</span></button>

  </form>

        {{key}}

    </div>
```

My View.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):

    return render(request,'DemoApp/hi.html')



def send(request):
    a=str(request.POST["Parameter"])
    b=str(request.POST["Condition"])
    c=str(request.POST["valuetomatch"])

    haha = a+b+c
    return render(request,'DemoApp/hi.html',{'key':haha})


# Create your views here.
```

My URL

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='home-page'),
    path('', views.send, name='test'),

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form has `<form action="send" method="post">`, but you do not have any url at `/send`. So you can change your urls.py file like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index,name='home-page'),
    path('send/', views.send, name='test'),

]
```

And you should consider using named urls in template(via [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)), like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'test' %}" method="post">
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your respond. It working now !